# Passing a scope variable to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can see my data in the `console.log` I just don't understand why I can't access it with `$scope.$parent.locations`. What am I missing?

**coupons.html**

```
<div id="coupons-grid" coupons-repeater="locations">
</div>

<!-- <p> When uncommented, below I can see all my location data <p> 
<p> {{ locations }} </p> -->
```

**directive**

```
.directive("couponsRepeater", function() {
  return {
    compile: function(elem, attr) {
      return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        console.log($scope.$parent); // in the console I see "locations" which is the data I need
        console.log($scope.$parent[$attr.couponsRepeater]); // comes back undefined - this is the call I would like to use because it's dynamic
        console.log($scope.$parent.locations); // comes back undefined
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**CouponsCtrl**

```
.controller('CouponsCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, $ionicLoading, userService) {
    $scope.locations = {one:1, two:2, three:3};
})
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit. You are trying to access `$scope.$parent` but you directive does not create a scope - was that your intention? Also, can you show how the directive and the controller interract? It works fine for me (I had to add `ng-if="true"` to create a scope):http://plnkr.co/edit/WKGegNI79f2EMTDnRYK9?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev +1 and I got it to work without the `ng-if`

Comment: yeah, you don't need `ng-if` - I just used it because I wasn't sure if your use of `$scope.$parent` was unintentional or whether something else was happening that you didn't post, so I "patched" it with `ng-if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$attr.couponsRepeater` is undefined where as `attr.couponsRepeater` has the value you are looking for.

On a side note, using `$parent` to access data is not a good idea, your directive should be using an isolated scope and the parent should pass data to it via other attributes. [Example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yynqjxvt/2/).

```
app.directive("couponsRepeater", function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          locations: '=couponsRepeater'
      },
      link:function (scope, ele, attrs) { 
          console.log(scope.locations);
      }
  }
});
```

With the HTML.

```
<div coupons-repeater="locations">
</div>
```

Comment: N.B. using `@` in the scope will pass the String "locations", using `=` will get the actual locations (`{one:1, two:2, three:3}`, in the question). Also, the directive doesn't have to be restricted to an `E` (element) tag, he can keep his markup by restricting to an `A` (attribute) tag and using `scope: { myVal: '=couponsRepeater' }`

Comment: Updated based on `locations` as object edit to question.

Comment: @DRobinson Restriction to `E` is to promote clear distinction between a directive and its scope attributes that bind. Allowing for `EA` or just `A` promotes hard to decipher HTML in my opinion. Didn't see advantage to pointing out all the options to a DDO. Thanks for picking up error re locations.

Comment: Didn't mention *all options*, I mentioned two. One you changed, because it was a mistake (`@` -> `=`), the other makes the directive more like the question was aiming for (`A` rather than `E`). Nor am I saying that `E` is bad, but `A` can be very useful for composability and shouldn't be entirely ignored (if that weren't the case, Angular wouldn't ship with so many built-in directives that are `A` restricted).

Comment: I have to be honest here guys, I don't know what you did but I can't even get the `console.log` to show anything with this code. Did you change something in the html as well?

Comment: @Jackson have a look at the JSFiddle link to show how it's working. @DRobinson, you're right I've added confusion and `A` are used heavily throughout angular, just find a lot less custom directives are created with that need, but that's just my experience.

Comment: I was using what @NewDev gave me but your code looks like it's following proper rules which I'm still trying to understand. Thanks again.